# What does `!+local_domains` in router specifications of exim4 config file mean?

Tags: smtp

Following several tutorials on how to configure exim4 (e.g. http://www.datadisk.org.uk/html_docs/exim/routers.htm) I started wondering what a good explanation for `!+local_domains` in the specification of routers could be, e.g.

```
smarthost:
   driver = manualroute
   transport = remote_smtp
   route_list = !+local_domains smarthost.example.com
```

What is the consequence of omitting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In exim configuration domainlist local_domains is used to store list of email domains that should be delivered to local (this hosts) mailboxes. Without `route_list = !+local_domains smarthost.example.com` even messages to `root@localhost` would be relayed to smarthost.